# How to get ArrayList from second Activity and show it in a Recycler view in the Main Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a Main Activity that start a Second Activity where countries are selected. In the Second Activity, when the user selects the countries and presses “Add”, I want to close the Second Activity and show the selected countries in a RecyclerView in the Main Activity. I’m not able to retrieve arraylist with selected countries in Main Activity. Any idea? Thank you.

[Main Activity][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMmL8.png

[Second Activity][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVMYS.jpg

Main Activity Code:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button addCountry;
    private RecyclerView countrySelectedRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarId);
        toolbar.setTitle("Main Activity");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        countrySelectedRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.idCountrySelectedRecyclerView);
        addCountry = findViewById(R.id.addCountryId);

        selectedCountryAdapter adapter = new selectedCountryAdapter();

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        countrySelectedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        countrySelectedRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        countrySelectedRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        addCountry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseCountry.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second Activity Code:

```js
public class ChooseCountry extends AppCompatActivity implements CountryListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_country);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarId);
        toolbar.setTitle("Second Activity");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        RecyclerView countryRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCoutryId);

        List<Countries> countriesList = new ArrayList<>();

        Countries unitedStates = new Countries();
        unitedStates.image = R.drawable.united_states;
        unitedStates.unselected = R.drawable.icon_unselected;
        unitedStates.country = "United States";
        countriesList.add(unitedStates);

        Countries italy = new Countries();
        italy.image = R.drawable.italy;
        italy.unselected = R.drawable.icon_unselected;
        italy.country = "Italy";
        countriesList.add(italy);

        Countries canada = new Countries();
        canada.image = R.drawable.canada;
        canada.unselected = R.drawable.icon_unselected;
        canada.country = "Canada";
        countriesList.add(canada);

        Countries spain = new Countries();
        spain.image = R.drawable.spain;
        spain.unselected = R.drawable.icon_unselected;
        spain.country = "Spain";
        countriesList.add(spain);

        final selectionCountryAdapter selectCountryAdapter = new selectionCountryAdapter(countriesList, this);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        countryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        countryRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        countryRecyclerView.setAdapter(selectCountryAdapter);

        //Arraylist with the selected countries
        List<Countries> newSelectedCountries = selectCountryAdapter.getSelectedCountries();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.idMenuAdd:

                //Required code

                finish();
                break;
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: There is a lots of work here ... Countries(should be rather Country) should be parcelable ... you should pass it with setResult(but first you have to call ChooseActivity with startActivityForResult) ... you should also save MainActivity countries list somewhere and add new ones in on ActivityResult ... as I wrote a lots of work - so this question doesn't fit SO

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve the result you are looking for.

If you want to continue using two activities, then save the selection in a [Room database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), and observe the Data using LiveData and a Query.

If you would like an easier solution, create two [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments):

1. Put all your first Activity's View related code in the first fragment.
2. Put your second Activity's View related code in the second fragment.

Then create a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) which both of your fragments will have access to. In your `optionsItemSelected()` just set a variable in the viewModel to a list of selected countries.

You can also move your country list initialization code into the ViewModel, which you can call from the second fragment's `onViewCreated()` callback.

Remove the second Activity because it can be replaced entirely by a Fragment. You can access `supportFragmentManager` from inside the first Activity, and then call `.beginTransaction()` followed by `.replace()` and `.commit()` to use Fragments.

Another benefit is that you don't have to initialize your Toolbar twice.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It helped me solve the problem.